# Check if my string contains elements from array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects and I wish to filter out those objects if my filter array matches the string of a key.

```
// my stores
var stores = [
    {
        id: 1,
        store: 'Store 1',
        storeSells: "Belts|Handbags|Watches|Wallets"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        store: 'Store 2',
        storeSells: "Handbags|Personal Accessories|Jewelry|Eyewear|"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        store: 'Store 3',
        storeSells: "Belts|Travel|Charms|Footwear|"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        store: 'Store 3',
        storeSells: "Charms|Footwear|"
    }
]

// my filters
var filters = ["Handbags","Belts"]
```

So, If my `filters` array has `handbags` and `belts`. I wish to filter stores with id's `1,2 and 3` only as they contains these keywords. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [**Array.prototype.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

[**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

And [**String.prototype.includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
// my stores
var stores = [
    {
        id: 1,
        store: 'Store 1',
        storeSells: "Belts|Handbags|Watches|Wallets"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        store: 'Store 2',
        storeSells: "Handbags|Personal Accessories|Jewelry|Eyewear|"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        store: 'Store 3',
        storeSells: "Belts|Travel|Charms|Footwear|"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        store: 'Store 3',
        storeSells: "Charms|Footwear|"
    }
]

// my filters
var filters = ["Handbags","Belts"];

var res = stores.filter(item => filters.some(i=>item.storeSells.includes(i)));
console.log(res);
```